# Saving a target URL's IP address as a variable string

Tags: php, arrays, search, ip, ping

I would like to store an ip address as a variable from a string.

So far I have created a quick ping command in PHP here:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('ping -c1 google.co.uk');
    if(preg_match_all('/\((.*?)\)/',$output,$match)) {
    var_dump($match[1]);
    }
?>
```

This outputs the following:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(12) "64.15.112.59" [1]=> string(2) "84" [2]=> string(13) "83.125.22.187" }
```

Within the above PHP command, I would like some help storing the first IP address (64.15.112.59).

I cannot find out how this is done. Maybe I'm doing things the wrong way, but I would like to know if this is possible :D

Comment: You don't know how to do `$match[1][0]`?

Comment: Thanks for that. It has managed to output: string(13) "64.15.112.109" 

But really I only want to save the text as a variable between the quotes.

Comment: Assign it to a variable. The other stuff is just the way `var_dump()` displays the details.

Comment: Do you really need to ping the site, or are you just doing that because you don't know any other way to get the IP (like the solutions in the answers)?

Comment: That is what I want to do. I need to know how to ignore everything outside the quotes (including the quotes!) and only save the IP as a variable.

Comment: Yeah I need the IP to confirm that the URL google.co.uk is reachable. The site however is not pingable so returns failures, but does output the external IP address. Which is what I want to capture in a variable.

Comment: There are no quotes to ignore. Those are just being output by `var_dump()`, they're not in the value. Do `echo $match[1][0]` and you'll see.

Answer (score 3):

There is a php function called `dns_get_record` that can help you to get the ip from the fqdn.

```
$ipInfo = dns_get_record('google.co.uk', DNS_A);

echo $ipInfo[0]['ip'];
```

The output for this echo is `74.125.132.94` (from my location)

For more information you can go to the PHP website: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Comment: That have worked perfectly. 2 lines versus my very amateur, buggy and actually longwinded 4 lines is excellent!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Also check out the complete output from the function (without the second parameter). It makes you smile ;)

Comment: oooOOOOooo I see what you did there! You stored the text from the result named "ip" oooo now I get to save as a variable woohoo you legend. Thanks once again ;)

Comment: Yup, just read a little bit about array's, then everything will fall into place ;). If this answer helped you, can you accept it as the 'accepted' answer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$ip = gethostbyname('google.co.uk');
```

And you will get IP stored in `$ip` variable. Also no need to preg_match, if function fails to get IP you will get bool false as result.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my finished coding with the help from **Benz** ;)

```
$ipInfo = dns_get_record('google.co.uk', DNS_A);
$ip = $ipInfo[0]['ip'];
```

Which outputs text to $ip variable.